# Which type of cover is album cover?

Tags: mp3, music, tags, id3

I am using this software called [mp3tag](http://www.mp3tag.de/en/) and I don't know if it's the right forum but it's clearly not their forum cause it's more about ID3 tags. Say I have a song. I have a band cover, an album cover, a specific song cover. How do I put them?

Clearly ID3 is made more for CDs that digital music with that "front cover" and "back cover" image tags, but what about albums and specific song covers. Which category would I assign them to, so that every player would understand this is the album with this album cover and this is one song from the album with a song cover?

Answer (score 1):

Specific song covers are usually single release covers. In the time and realm when ID3 was invented there was no digital release so only a single would have a different cover to an album. In that case the picture you would have would be respective to the kind of release you bought (single/album/best of/compilation etc etc).

I would state that they are singles or bootleg releases and simply fill the album tags with that, if at all. Remember, not every field must be filled.

Amendment, if you are talking strictly ID3v2 image tags, Album Covers should be $03 and Song covers should be $12. See here for more: http://www.richardfarrar.com/embedding-album-art-in-mp3-files/

Comment: I'll try with a music player. so 03 and 12

Comment: No, I put it as you say, media player gives me there on the right the album cover instead of song cover, and in albums gives me song cover. Maybe it's the other way around?

Comment: Blame the software industry not really having methods of collecting feedback. If iTunes, for example, by default showed album covers, I would imagine the industry would switch them so they are still seen.